# Remove a term from managed metadata column

Tags: term, mms

I have a listitem with a managed metadata column. the column has two values (two terms) . now i need to remove one from it. how to do that programmatically (server side object model). i have given the screenshot for reference.

[image]

when my code executes, i have to remove chap1 term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the answer in my blog. 
http://sharepointplays.blogspot.in/2016/11/remove-term-from-managed-metadata.html

`TaxonomyFieldValueCollection tfc = oListItem["TodoColumn"] as TaxonomyFieldValueCollection;
                        tfc.Remove(tfc.Where(i => i.Label.Equals("Lesson 1")).FirstOrDefault());
                        oListItem["TodoColumn"] = tfc;`